# is there a point to increase testorone and is it actually possible?

Tags: testosterone

many ads on the internet about increasing testorone, and everywhere you go where the argument is fitness there's aleays guys preaching about how not masturbating, eating steaks and 12 eggs a day while squatting heavy weight increases testosterone.

But I was thinking, admitted it is actually possible to increase testorone without injections or other medicines... isn't it stupid to do so?

if there isn't much testorone in your blood that's usually a good thing, it means your muscles and bones are absorbing it and you don't have free testorone causing cancers in your butt which is the 2nd most common cancer on the planet.... and cancer in general is the 2nd biggest killer worldwide after cardiovascular disease.

worldwide about 10 million people die of cancer, so increasing testorone, the one hormone which drives cancer growth to insane speeds seems the worst choice ever.

Comment: Vote close because whether there's a point in increasing T is entirely opinion-based. Is your main excercising goal to stay healthy? Just focus on a balanced nutrition. Are you an actor that needs to get shredded asap because your last role was a skinny lunatic and your and your next one will be a buff super hero? Then steroids might be a valid option. It depends on your goals, your circumstances and your willingness to take risks. Maybe focus your question more on the 'Is it actually possible?' part, because that's actually answerable in a general sense.

Comment: Increasing testosterone within normal ranges doesn't generally change much. It's typically only superphysiological increases in testosterone that make a difference. Such increases only come through either puberty or pharmaceuticals. Now if your testosterone levels are lower than normal because you're doing everything to make them low (getting less sleep, eating in a deficit, eating low fat, low bf%, etc.) and then start doing everything right you might see an appreciable difference, but otherwise you're going to need some pharmaceutical assistance to see notable changes.